# Laravel 5.1 - Merge multiple Eloquent queries and sort by timestamp

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have three tables, a Users table, a Jobs table and a Bids table. Users can post multiple Jobs and Users can post a bid on Jobs which are not their's.

**My Goal: I'm trying to query the Jobs table to find all of a users jobs and query the Bids table to get all of the jobs that a user is bidding on. Then I would like to sort the jobs and bids based on their timestamps and return job IDs**

The tables are setup as follows:

```
| USERS    | JOBS    | BIDS
| id       | id      | id
| username | user_id | user_id
| password | title   | job_id
|          |         | bid_amount
```

The relationships between the tables are as follows:

Jobs:

```
public function bids()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\RocketCandy\Repos\Bids\Bid');
}

public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\RocketCandy\Repos\Users\User');
}
```

Users:

```
public function jobs()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\RocketCandy\Repos\Jobs\Job');
}

public function bids()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\RocketCandy\Repos\Bids\Bid');
}
```

Bids:

```
public function jobs()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\RocketCandy\Repos\Jobs\Job');
}

public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\RocketCandy\Repos\Users\User');
}
```

The following code I've developed returns the jobs and the bids but it's not clever enough to sort the IDs based on the updated_at timestamp.

```
public function getUsersJobs($userId)
{
    // Get the jobs that the user posted
    $postedJobs = Job::where('user_id', $userId)
                       ->lists('id')
                       ->toArray();

    // Get the jobs that the user is bidding on
    $biddedJobs = Job::with('bids')
                       ->whereHas('bids', function ($q) use ($userId) {
                           $q->where('user_id', $userId);
                       })->lists('id')
                         ->toArray();

    $jobIds = array_merge($postedJobs, $biddedJobs);

    // Return the jobs that a user has posted and is bidding on
    return Job::whereIn('id', $jobIds)
                       ->OrderBy('updated_at', 'DESC')
                       ->get();
}
```

Comment: Typo with orderBy clause? it should be ->orderBy NOT ->OrderBy

Comment: Okay valid point but what about an answer?

Comment: Sorry, I don't get what you want to achieve here. So what's missing with the code that you write after you fixed the typo? is it still not sorting the IDs?

Comment: So basically I want to get all of the Jobs that a user has posted by id. I want to get all of the bids a user has made by job_id. Return them all to the user (so he can see a combined view of bidded and posted jobs) but sort them based on the 'updated_at' timestamp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can simplify it a lot by looking at it from the User instead of the Job:

```
$jobs = User::where('user_id', $userId)->jobs;
$bids = User::where('user_id', $userId)->bids;

$all = $jobs->toBase()->merge($bids)->sortByDesc('updated_at');

foreach ($all as $thing) {
    dump($thing->id);
    dump($thing->updated_at);
}
```